# Remove all __pycache__/ folders from git history

Tags: git, version-control

`__pycache__/` was not added to the `.gitignore`, resulting in `__pycache__/` folders being tracked and committed throughout the git history.

I've attempted this command to remove it from the entire git history

```bash
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch __pycache__/" HEAD
```

Which seems to have worked for the `__pycache__/` in the top-level root directory, but subfolders still have their own `__pycache__/` folders, despite the `-r` recursive flag used.

How can I remove all instances of `__pycache__/` throughout all folders from a git history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive flag `-r` doesn't mean "find the pattern all over the tree", it means "find top-level directory(ies) that match the pattern and remove everything below these directories recursively". To remove a pattern all over the tree you also need to use recursive pattern:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch */__pycache__/*" HEAD
```

*Upd*. Using [git-filter-repo](/questions/tagged/git-filter-repo):

```
git filter-repo --force --path-glob '*/__pycache__/' --invert-paths
```

Comment: This variant doesn't seem to have an effect either. `Rewrite 65194b3263d555c27f273b2523acf47e0a9629b9 (14/14) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/main' is unchanged`

Comment: Looks like I was able to fix it with `git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch *.pyc" HEAD`

Comment: @MichaelMoreno Fixed and tested in a real repo. The central part for the fix is `git rm --cached */__pycache__/*` — i.e., remove files, not directories.

Comment: @MichaelMoreno Yeat another update: using `git filter-repo`.